# Product URL is not showing properly in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento version 2.3.5-p1 I am working on the Multistore website. I have created one more store (abc). But the product URL is not showing properly only for this particular store (abc). Other store views its working fine. Admin configuration also same for all the store views.
**Ex: Product URL**
`http://localhost.us/catalog/product/view/id/1673/s/productname`

How to remove `catalog/product/view/id/1673/s/` from this product URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this by adding a rewrite rule for that particular store. Other stores are already having rewrite rules for that particular products.